# Wrap collection to XMLTYPE in PL/SQL (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

smart guys!

Lets say I have a table:

```
id NUMBER     name VARCHAR2       info XMLTYPE
--
1             Brad              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-5"?>
2             Angelina          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-5"?>
```

In my package I can select it to some collection variable **v_table**.

And I need to convert it to XML and return XMLTYPE, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-5"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <id type="NUMBER">1</id>
        <name type="VARCHAR2">Brad</name>
        <info type="XMLTYPE"><!-- somehow insert here xml, maybe base64 encoded --></info>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id type="NUMBER">2</id>
        <name type="VARCHAR2">Angelina</name>
        <info type="XMLTYPE"><!-- somehow insert here xml, maybe base64 encoded --></info>
    </row>
</rows>
```

So I need to make some universal function to convert any collection to XML. Unfortunately I don't know PL/SQL (only MySQL, MsSQL), and I just don't know the right way to start. Could you give me some advice?

PS: "type" attribute is not required, but would be cool.

Comment: Does it have to convert a collection or would it be enough to have a function that directly converts SQL into XML?  The package [DBMS_XMLGEN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS374) already does that.  For example: `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from dual') from dual;`.  Then you could perhaps apply a stylesheet to the results through the XMLType function TRANSFORM.

Comment: I knew that I just don't know something obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Jon Heller!

> The package DBMS_XMLGEN already does that. For example: select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from dual') from dual;. Then you could perhaps apply a stylesheet to the results through the XMLType function TRANSFORM.